# Java Flight Recorder exports in different file format?

Tags: java, jmc

The user interface of *Java Mission Control* `jmc` allows me to generate *Flight Recorder* recordings. In the *Start Flight Recording* dialog, I can enter the name of a recording file to generate, like `test.jfr`:

[image]

I realized that the generated file doesn't have the same format as the files generated when running the Java application with flags like:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=15s,filename=/tmp/test2.jfr
```

The first three bytes of `test2.jfr` are `FLR` and I can parse this file (as described [here](http://hirt.se/blog/?p=446)) – unlike the file obtained from `jmc`.

**Question:** Is there a way to save recordings taken in the `jmc` user interface in the file format that the parsers understand?

(I am aware that the parsers are unsupported.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter how you start the recording, from command line or JMC, the file format is the same. However, when transferring data over JMX it is always compressed using gzip. It could be that JMC writes it in compressed format.

This information is for JDK 7/8.